# Probability - Flip coin twice

Tags: probability

The question is about a twice fair coin flip (head or tail).

event A: first flip is head

event B: second flip is head

event C: both flips show the same

I thought of the following probabilities:

$P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = 1/2$

$P(A \cap C) = 1/4$

$P(B \cap C) = 1/4$

But I need help with calculating $P((A \cup B) \cap C)$ and $P(A \cup B)$.

Comment: Hint: Think about the 4 equally likely outcomes $HH,TT,HT,TH$ which outcomes staisfy $A\cup B$ etc?

Comment: There are only four possibilities, so just list them and see if $A \cup B$ and $(A \cup B)\cap C$ are true for each one.